# Parsing JSON in javascript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm pulling my hair out over this. I am using jQuery.getJSON() method to get a response from a server. This is an example reponse:

```
{
  "playlist": {
      "track": {
          "song": "Wake me up",
          "albumart": "http://example.com/image.png",
          "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA"
      }
  }
}
```

There will be more than one track in the response, but only one playlist. I am requesting this using the following:

```
$.getJSON("api/playlist/get.php", {artist: "artist+name" })
```

How do I go about parsing this data?

Comment: You need to add a success function to your getJSON call. The JSON string will parse to an object that you can then access it's properties as you would any other JS object. The jquery api for getJSON has an example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your JSON result is like this:

```
{

    "playlist": {
        "track": {
            "song": "Wake me up",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA"
        },
        "track": {
            "song": "Wake me up 2",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image2.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA2"
        },
        "track": {
            "song": "Wake me up 3",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image3.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA3"
        }
    }
}
```

## UPDATE:

This json is invalid format, because it has multiple sub-objects with same property name.
If you are able, change response from server into this format:

```
{
    playlist: {
        tracks: [{
            "song": "Wake me up",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA"
        }, {
            "song": "Wake me up 2",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image2.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA2"
        }, {
            "song": "Wake me up 3",
            "albumart": "http://example.com/image3.png",
            "videoid": "CDsKBof4iMA3"
        }]
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to get each `track` object from passed Array:

You should use you `$.getJSON` function like this:

```
$.getJSON("api/playlist/get.php", function (data) {

    for (var key in myObj.playlist.tracks) {
        //do something with your track object
        console.log(myObj.playlist.tracks[key].song)
    }

})
```

Here is JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/Fy6ud/1/

Comment: I keep getting undefined error which is on the console.log() line

Comment: @JamesWalker I just updated my post. You get `undefined`, because your JSON response is in invalid format. It has multiple objects with same property name.

If you are able to change JSON sender file from server, then change it into correct format, as suggested: put objects into array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never even thought that the JSON response may have been incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseJSON()` to get a JavaScript object of the JSON.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: You don't need to use parseJSON if you use getJSON as it returns an object in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("api/playlist/get.php", function(data) {
    var responseObject = JSON.parse(data);
    // do stuff with responseObject
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/),

```
 jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) ] )
```

In this, the `success( data, textStatus, jqXHR )` is the callback if the JSON load was successful